# Basic select deadlocks itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-deadlocks

So, I have been looking into more SQL server management tools using a few of them, and I have been amazed to find simple selects blocking themselves and causing deadlocks. I have done a little research, but I am truly amazed this could happen. Can anyone clarify, or maybe solve, why this happens?

I'm talking about a simple select.

```
 SELECT
     ID
 FROM   
     MainTable
 WHERE 
     Name Like 'John Smith'
```

Using Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studios, if it matters.

Comment: How do you know it deadlocks itself? Can you describe what you're actually seeing?

Comment: This will not cause a deadlock on its own.

Comment: If you are inserting to the database at the same time you are selecting that data, your query may be chosen as a deadlock victim.  If you dont care about seeing the data that has just been inserted, you can add `with nolock` after your table name and it will do a "dirty" read and there will be no deadlock.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I am using SQL DIagnostic tool, and Phil, either my tool is lieing, or you are incorrect...

Comment: @CalvinSmith another option is that you are misinterpreting your tool's output. What happens when you execute that select statement? How long does it take? What error do you get? What does SQL Diagnostic say about it?

Comment: Did you get a deadlock victim error returned from this statement? It would be helpful to see what info you are seeing that indicated this was deadlocked, i.e. an error message or something.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2000 processes would sometimes report as blocking themselves, but I don't think this applies in later versions of SQL Server.

[latch waits reported as blocking](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/906344)

It is definitely possible for a SELECT statement to cause a deadlock, because shared locks are acquired when data is selected, but there would also have to be another process that is trying to update the data.

Comment: Actually the shared lock (unless we are in a transaction with REPEATABLE READ Isolation Level - or worse-) would be held for just a fraction of time and then suddenly released, at least on single rows or keys.

Answer (score 0):

A parallel execution plan can show as a SPID blocking itself.  This is basically just threads waiting for the other tasks in the query to complete.  Deadlocking is another matter, caused by different sessions waiting on each other.  Deadlocks (and excessive parallelism) can be a symptom of the need for query and index tuning.

If you are running SQL 2008 or later, deadlock information is captured by the system_helath extended event trace by default.  Below is a query to extract recent deadlock information from the ring buffer.  This will eliminate some of the guesswork.

```
SELECT
       xed.value('@timestamp', 'datetime') as Creation_Date,
       xed.query('.') AS Extend_Event
FROM
(
       SELECT CAST([target_data] AS XML) AS Target_Data
       FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xt
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xs
       ON xs.address = xt.event_session_address
       WHERE xs.name = N'system_health'
       AND xt.target_name = N'ring_buffer'
) AS XML_Data
CROSS APPLY Target_Data.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData(xed)
ORDER BY Creation_Date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple select cannot deadlock itself, the only possible cause is something else is updating/deleting rows while you are reading.
Try launching SQL Server Profiler and use the:

- deadlock
- deadlock chain
- deadloch graph

events in your template.
The Deadlock graph in particular will help you identify which two processes are causing trhe deadlock and the one chosen as deadlock victim